# iOS Calendar Extensions

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

Is there such as thing as a calendar extension on iOS?

I’m writing a simple app which does only one thing, which is to add a special event to the selected calendar. It works, but it seems to be too small a task for a full app.

Is there any way to incorporate this with the standard Calendar app?